# Reactjs Update the state without reload the page

Tags: reactjs

I built a shopping cart in my app. This is the flow:
- The customer sees a list of items and clicks on one he wants;
- The next page is where he chooses the quantity of products and then I save in localStorage;
- By clicking Confirm, he goes to the shopping cart with the same products he has chosen. On this page (shopping cart) he can change the quantity and in this moment the total and quantity must change (see the image).
I was able to do this reloading the page, but when in production the page is not working properly. I need to do this without reload the page.
How to do this without reload the page?
I got 3 components: Header (with the icon cart), ChooseQuantity and Cart.
See below the code:
[image]

```js
//My Choose Quantity Component
import React from 'react';
import '../../components/ChooseQuantity/ChooseQuantity.css';

class ChooseQuantity extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { lotQuantity, totalQuantity, maxTotalItems, maxPurchase, lot, totalTickets, events, onChange } = this.props;
        this.state = {
            counter: 0,
            lotQuantity: lotQuantity,
            totalQuantity: totalQuantity,
            maxTotalItems: maxTotalItems,
            maxPurchase: maxPurchase,
            totalTickets: totalTickets,
            onChange: onChange,
            events: events,
            lot: lot,
            tickets: events.tickets,
            cart: []

        }
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
        this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log(this.state.lot);
        // localStorage.setItem('teste', JSON.stringify(this.state.lotQuantity));
    }

    // static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    //     console.log(props.lot);
    //     // console.log(state);
    //     if (props.selected !== state.selected) {
    //         return {
    //             selected: props.selected,
    //         };
    //     }
    // }

    // componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    //     console.log(this.props.lot);
    //     localStorage.setItem('teste', JSON.stringify(this.props.lot.quantity));
    //     if (this.props.lot !== prevProps.lot) {
    //         // this.selectNew();
    //     }
    // }

    async increment() {
        await this.setState({
            lotQuantity: this.state.lotQuantity + 1,
            totalQuantity: + 1,
        });
        let lotUniqueNumber = this.state.lot.lotUniqueNumber;
        let lotQuantity = this.state.lotQuantity;
        var ar_lot = [];
        this.state.tickets.lot.forEach(function (item) {
            if (lotUniqueNumber === item.lotUniqueNumber) {
                item.quantity = lotQuantity;
                item.total = item.totalLotPrice * item.quantity
            }
            ar_lot.push(item);
        })
        // console.log(ar_lot);

        //CALCULATING A QUANTITY
        var ob_qtd = ar_lot.reduce(function (prevVal, elem) {
            const ob_qtd = prevVal + elem.quantity;
            return ob_qtd;
        }, 0);
        await this.setState({ totalTickets: ob_qtd })
        //CALCULATING A QUANTITY

        //CALCULATING THE TOTAL
        var ob_total = ar_lot.reduce(function (prevVal, elem) {
            const ob_total = prevVal + elem.total;
            return ob_total;
        }, 0);
        // CALCULATING THE TOTAL

        //RIDING THE SHOPPING CART
        let total = {
            price: ob_total,
            totalQuantity: ob_qtd,
        };

        let tickets = {
            name: this.state.tickets.name,
            prevenda: this.state.tickets.prevenda,
            unique_number: this.state.tickets.unique_number,
            lot: ar_lot
        }
        let events = {
            banner_app: this.state.events.banner_app,
            installments: this.state.events.installments,
            max_purchase: this.state.events.max_purchase,
            name: this.state.events.name,
            tickets: tickets
        }
        var cart = { events: events, total: total };
        this.setState({
            cart: cart
        })
        // console.log(cart);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));//RECORDING CART IN LOCALSTORAGE
        localStorage.setItem('qtd', JSON.stringify(ob_qtd));
        window.location.reload();//UPDATE PAGE FOR CHANGES TO BE UPDATED
    }

    async decrement() {
        await this.setState({
            lotQuantity: this.state.lotQuantity - 1,
            totalQuantity: - 1,
            totalTickets: this.state.totalTickets - 1,
        });

        let lotUniqueNumber = this.state.lot.lotUniqueNumber;

        let lotQuantity = this.state.lotQuantity;
        var ar_lot = [];
        this.state.tickets.lot.forEach(function (item) {
            if (lotUniqueNumber === item.lotUniqueNumber) {
                item.quantity = lotQuantity;
                item.total = item.totalLotPrice * item.quantity
            }
            ar_lot.push(item);
        })

        //CALCULANDO A QUANTIDADE
        var ob_qtd = ar_lot.reduce(function (prevVal, elem) {
            const ob_qtd = prevVal + elem.quantity;
            return ob_qtd;
        }, 0);
        //CALCULANDO A QUANTIDADE

        //CALCULANDO O TOTAL
        var ob_total = ar_lot.reduce(function (prevVal, elem) {
            const ob_total = prevVal + elem.total;
            return ob_total;
        }, 0);
        //CALCULANDO O TOTAL

        let total = {
            price: ob_total,
            totalQuantity: ob_qtd,
        };

        let tickets = {
            name: this.state.tickets.name,
            prevenda: this.state.tickets.prevenda,
            unique_number: this.state.tickets.unique_number,
            lot: ar_lot
        }
        let events = {
            banner_app: this.state.events.banner_app,
            installments: this.state.events.installments,
            max_purchase: this.state.events.max_purchase,
            name: this.state.events.name,
            tickets: tickets
        }
        var cart = { events: events, total: total };
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
        localStorage.setItem('qtd', JSON.stringify(ob_qtd));
        window.location.reload();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="choose-quantity">
                {
                    this.state.lotQuantity <= 0 ?
                        <div className="space-button"></div> :
                        <button className='minus' onClick={this.decrement}><i className="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                }
                <div id='counter' className="qtd" value={this.state.lotQuantity} onChange={this.onChange}>{this.state.lotQuantity}</div>
                {
                    this.state.totalTickets >= this.state.maxPurchase ?
                        <div className="space-button"></div> :
                        <button className="plus" onClick={() => this.increment(this.state.lotQuantity)}><i className="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default ChooseQuantity;
```

```js
//My Shopping Cart Component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './Cart.css';
import '../../components/Css/App.css';

import Lot from './Lot';
import ChooseQuantity from './ChooseQuantity';

import Header from '../../components/Header/Header';
import Tabbar from '../../components/Tabbar/Tabbar';

const separator = '/';
class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
        this.choosePayment = this.choosePayment.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const company_info = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('company_info'));
        await this.setState({ 
            company_image: company_info.imagem,
            company_hash: company_info.numeroUnico,
        })
        const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        const total = cart.total;
        if(cart){
            const {
                events,
                events: { tickets },
                total
              } = cart;
            await this.setState({
                cart,
                events,
                tickets: tickets,
                banner_app: events.banner_app,
                eventName: cart.events.name,
                priceTotal: total.price,
                quantity: total.totalQuantity,
                lots: tickets.lot,
                maxTotalItems: cart.events.max_purchase,
                selectedLots: tickets.lot,
                total: total.totalQuantity
            });
        }

        const teste = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('teste'))
        this.setState({teste: teste})
    }    

    choosePayment() {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Método de Pagamento',
            text: 'Qual o médtodo de pagamento que você deseja usar?',
            confirmButtonText: 'Cartão de Crédito',
            confirmButtonColor: '#007bff',
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonText: 'Boleto Bancário',
            cancelButtonColor: '#007bff',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                this.props.history.push('/checkout');
            } else{
                this.props.history.push('/checkout-bank-slip');
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header Title="Carrinho" ToPage="/" />
                {
                    this.state.total <= 0 ?
                    <Tabbar />
                    :
                    null
                }
                <div className="cart">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        {
                            this.state.total > 0 ?
                            <div>
                                <div className="box-price">
                                    <div className="row box-default ">
                                        <div className="col col-price">
                                            <h6>{this.state.quantity} INGRESSO{this.state.quantity > 1 ? 'S' : ''}</h6>
                                            <h5>R$ {parseFloat(this.state.priceTotal).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')}</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-12 col-image no-padding">
                                        <img src={this.state.banner_app} alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <h1 className="event-title text-center">{this.state.eventName}</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="padding-15">
                                    {
                                        this.state.lots.map((lot, l) => 
                                        <div key={l}>
                                            {
                                                lot.quantity > 0 ?
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div className="row">
                                                            <div className="col">
                                                                <h5 className="ticket-name">{lot.ticketName}</h5>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="row">
                                                            <div className="col-8">
                                                                <h5 className="lot-name">
                                                                    { lot.lotName } - ({lot.lotNumber}º Lote)
                                                                </h5>
                                                                <h6 className="lot-price">
                                                                    R$ {lot.lotPrice.replace('.', ',')} ({lot.lotPrice.replace('.', ',')} + {lot.lotPriceTax.replace('.', ',')})
                                                                </h6>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-4">
                                                                <h3 className='lot-big-price'>
                                                                    {lot.lotPrice.replace('.', ',')}
                                                                </h3>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="row">
                                                            <div className="col align-items">
                                                                <ChooseQuantity
                                                                    lotQuantity={lot.quantity}
                                                                    maxPurchase={this.state.events.max_purchase}
                                                                    totalTickets={this.state.total}
                                                                    lot={lot}
                                                                    events={this.state.events}
                                                                    maxTotalItems={this.state.maxTotalItems}
                                                                    onCLick={this.onClick}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    :
                                                null

                                            }
                                        </div>
                                        )
                                    }
                                    
                                    <div className="row cart-footer" style={{ marginRight: '-15px', marginLeft: '-15px', backgroundColor: '#f4f7fa' }}>
                                        <button className="col col-purchase" style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} onClick={this.choosePayment}>
                                            Confirmar Comprar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            :
                            <div className='padding-15'>
                                <div className="mt-5 no-margin box-default row">
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <h3 className="text-center">
                                            Não há nenhum item em seu carrinho.
                                        </h3>
                                        <p className="text-center">        
                                            Toque no botão <strong>Buscar Eventos</strong> para iniciar uma nova pesquisa.         
                                        </p>
                                        <Link className="btn btn-primary btn-block" to="/">
                                            Buscar Eventos
                                        </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="row no-margin box-default mt-3">
                                    <div className="col">
                                        <img src={`//www.yeapps.com.br/admin/files/empresa/${this.state.company_hash}/${this.state.company_image}`} alt={`${this.state.company_name}`} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Cart;
```

```js
//My Header Component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import './Header.css';
import BackButton from '../BackButton/BackButton';

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            qtd: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const qtd = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('qtd'));
        this.setState({qtd: qtd});
    }

    render() {
        const { Title } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar">
                    { this.props.Title === 'Home' ? null : <BackButton />}
                    <Link to="/cart" className="icon-cart">
                        <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        <span className="badge badge-danger">
                            {this.state.qtd}
                        </span>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="navbar-brand">
                        {Title}
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: At which step is the page reloading ? Also could you try to simplify your code abit more if possible ?

Comment: I wll update the code with comments

Comment: Have you considered using a parent component to hold the state ?
Parent can then pass data as props to each child component and with a callback to update state and localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your presentational components(Card,Header) state in componentDidUpdate the same way as you did it in componentDidMount. componentDidMount works only one time with first render and there you set your state variables which you use in render. Do the same setState in componentDidUpdate

P.S. but you need to be sure that with counter increasing your presentational components get new props which will trigger componentDidUpdate.In your case you use localStorage but it will be better to pass data through common parent container(the one which holds those 3 components) as props to Card and Header.

Comment: Sorry man I studied all weekend and couldn't do it . I'm very dumb

Comment: Don't disappoint about that, in the beginning, it could be hard for anyone. Read more on the official site about the lifecycle of components and passing data between components. Or start an online course where everything will be explained from the very begging